# getting 404 at running application root on eclipse/tomcat8

Tags: spring, tomcat8

I'm using Eclipse and Tomcat 8. I created a dynamic web project, using Spring. This is my **web.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>Spring Open Hospital</display-name>
<description>Spring Open Hospital sample application</description>


<!-- When using Spring JDBC, use the following: -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/business-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller 
    implementations). -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>oh</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-core-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>oh</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- used to provide the ability to enter Chinese characters inside the 
    Owner Form -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<!-- used so we can use forms of method type 'PUT' and 'DELETE' see here: 
    http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#rest-method-conversion -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>oh</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

**business-config.xml** file contains informations about datasource definition and component scan for repository and service beans.

My **mvc-core-config.xml** file contains following lines:

```
<!-- uses WebJars so Javascript and CSS libs can be declared as Maven dependencies 
    (Bootstrap, jQuery...) -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**"
    location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />

<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="welcome" />

<!-- serve static resources (*.html, ...) from src/main/webapp/ Required 
    when both servlet-mapping is '/' and static resources need to be served -->
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />


<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <!-- view name resolved using bean of type InternalResourceViewResolver 
        (declared in mvc-view-config.xml) -->
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="exception" />
    <!-- results into 'WEB-INF/jsp/exception.jsp' -->
    <property name="warnLogCategory" value="warn" />
    <!-- needed otherwise exceptions won't be logged anywhere -->
</bean>
```

and the **mvc-view.config.xml** file contains:

```
<mvc:view-resolvers>
    <mvc:content-negotiation use-not-acceptable="true">
        <mvc:default-views>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
                <property name="url" value="" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:default-views>
    </mvc:content-negotiation>

    <mvc:jsp prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" suffix=".jsp" />
</mvc:view-resolvers>
```

So, after running tomcat server, opening my application at **localhost:8080/oh**, I get a 404 page, but I was expecting my welcome.jsp page.

Opening the tomcat page at localhost:8080 and listing installed applications, **oh** application is correctly deployed.

What I'm doing wrong?

If I use tomcat7 maven plugin:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
                <port>9966</port>
                <path>/oh</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and after running:  `mvn tomcat7:run`, opening web application at url: 
http://localhost:9966/oh/

welcome page is correctly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

For your "oh" servlet you specified a `/`url-pattern, so the URL to your welcome page is **localhost:8080/name_of_web_project**

If you want your servlet to be accessed at **localhost:8080/name_of_web_project/oh** you have to give the `/oh`path in your servlet-mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>oh</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/oh</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm unsure if you have to modify the `<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="welcome" />`accordingly too as I've never used that, please let me know.

Comment: I've tried both giving the /oh path in my servlet mapping and modifying the <mvc:view-controller path="/oh" view-name="welcome" />, but it doesn't work yet, still getting 404.

If I use tomca7 maven plugin:

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
     <port>9966</port>
     <path>/oh</path>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

and running mvn tomcat7:run, everything works fine, with my original web.xml

Comment: When you use the maven plugin you specify /oh as a path to your application, not your servlet, so according to your mapping the welcome page should be at `localhost:9966/oh/oh

Comment: When deploying with eclipse, did you try accessing your page at localhost:8080/NAME_OF_YOUR_WAR/oh ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. We both missed that your path starts with the name of your web app.

Comment: I've tried adding to path the name of web app, but I still get 404. I've tried all the possible combinations, I'm not able to display my welcome page at all. I'm able to make it works just with tomcat7 maven plugin. If you want, I can provide you my public repo url, so you can pull the code.

Comment: I've imported your project in eclipse and published it on a tomcat 7 runtime  within eclipse. I just changed the java facet to have it run on java 6. 
I modified the web.xml and the mvc-core-config.xml file, adding the /oh path like we discussed : `<mvc:view-controller path="/oh" view-name="welcome" />` and `<url-pattern>/oh</url-pattern>`.
I manage to access the welcome page at localhost:8080/oh/oh.
This means that the name of your webapp is **oh** (and not SpringOH). I looked into the pom and found : `<name>oh</name>
  <packaging>war</packaging>`, so it makes sense...

Comment: I did the same on Tomcat 8 and had no issue accessing the welcome page. When you launch Tomcat with eclipse, do you have anything strange going on inside the console ?

Comment: The only strange thing that I saw on console, launching Tomcat, is:

`WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringOH' did not find a matching property.`

I'm going to try with Tomcat7 runtime within eclipse, I'll let you know. Thanks, @AdrianFraisse

Comment: Man I think maybe your setup is simply broken for some reason. Try cleaning your Tomcat work directory, cleaning and publishing again... It seems like your issue was with your server all along :(

Comment: If not of the above works, try checking out your code clean and then importing it again into eclipse, generating the conf files with `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, that's what I did on my setup…